# How can I come back to previous php page when I call another php?

Tags: php, user-interface, navigation

I have 2 PHP pages. In the first page, I am clicking a button which redirects to another file via `<a>` tag and does its work(sending mail). but now I want once that page functionality is done it should come to the previous page without any user action. How can I do that?

include once is not the solution since it just calls other php. I need to come back to the same page, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution you can go back to the previous page using javascript.

There is one object in DOM called History you can use that in onload event:-

forexample https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_go.asp

```
window.History.go(-1);
```

Comment: but it is throwing 
Warning: Use of undefined constant window - assumed 'window' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)